# XCAP xml format

Tags: xml, xpath, jitsi, jitsi-meet

i'm trying to upload contacts to jitsi SIP account using XCAP server option and using my SIP server as XCAP server
i want to know XML format supported by XCAP , my XML file format is as below. but my XCAP Server not getting it while requesting that file and returns

> 2019-07-11 18:52:15.306 SEVERE: [659]
>   impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logError().133 Error from the JAIN-SIP
>   stack: Invalid argument address = ::0 port = 5060 transport = UDP
>   2019-07-11 18:52:16.489 SEVERE: [671]
>   impl.protocol.sip.ServerStoredContactListSipImpl.init().646 Error
>   while connecting to XCAP server. Contact list won't be saved
>   net.java.sip.communicator.impl.protocol.sip.xcap.XCapException: XCAP
>   server returns invalid content type: application/xcap-el+xml

i have created xml file as below, have tried content type: application/xml as well but not working

[image: XML file]